# What are Encryption/Decryption Key Management Best Praticies

Tags: encryption, cryptography

I am developing a web based application that will be employed by numerous third party organisations
in numerous countries around the world.

The browser based client will feed sensitive data into a shared back end database.

All organisations in all countries will Read/Write data into the same database.

I wish to encrypt the data entered within the browser so that its safe while in transit
to the back end database. e.g. client side encryption.

I also wish to encrypt the data while at rest in my database.

This application will be developed using Java, Javascript (REACT.js), and Scala.

The backend database will be MongoDB.

I cannot find a good Key Management example/description e.g. how a key is properly generated,
distributed, stored, replaced, deleted, and recovered during its life time.

I have the following choices/decisions to make:-

Flavour of encryption, e.g TripleDES, RSA, Blowfish, Twofish, AES etc..
Key(s) Symmetric/Asymmetric and its/thier length
How should I securely distribute the keys to my clients.
How to keep my keys safe on my back end servers.

If keys should have a lifecycle of generated, distributed, stored, replaced, deleted.
How do I decrypt data that was encrypted with Key0 when I am now using Key1, or Key2?

How should I store my multiple keys for my multiple clients to enable me to encrypt/decrypt
each clients data.

Comment: This is probably better suited for http://security.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use HTTPS with certificate pinning to secure the data in transit.
2. Use AES for encryption. Do not use TripleDES, RSA, Blowfish or Twofish in new work.
3. Use an [HSM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module).
4. Encrypt the data with a long-life key that is not distributed, encrypt that key with short life keys that can be changed as needed.
5. Considering the scope of the project get a cryptographic domain expert to design the security and vet the code.

Comment: thanks very much for your suggestions. just what I required.